# Salvar data no formato brasileiro no Postgresql

Tags: c#, asp.net, postgresql, microsoft-azure, timestamp

Eu tenho um banco de dados PostgreSQL no servidor Windows Azure que está configurado para o padrão brasileiro.

Se eu faço um SQL e executo direto no PgAdminIII lá do servidor e executo, a data fica salva no formato brasileiro.

Mas se eu mando meu código C# (local ou no Azure) executar o SQL, a data fica salva no formato Americano. Já fiz um debug no meu código e vi que a data está brasileira, ele monta a string SQL com a data brasileira, mas quando executa ela fica salva como americana.

Tanto o código quanto meu acesso direto ao PgAdminIII do Postgre estão com o mesmo usuário. Porque isso acontece? Porque executando manualmente fica brasileiro e quando o código executa fica americano? Alguém consegue ajudar, por favor? Já tiveram problema parecido?

Comment: Qual a cultura configurada em sua aplicação?!

Comment: Poderias postar o respectivo trecho do seu código C#, por favor?

Comment: Eu tive um problema parecido e resolvi colcando essa tag   ´<globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />´  no webconfig dentro da tag ´<system.web>´, ou entao configurar na globlal.asax.

Answer (score 3):

Eu conheço duas formas de forçar a cultura no Asp.net

> Primeira:

No `web.config` dentro da tag `<system.web>` você adiciona a seguinte tag

```
 <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />
```

> Segunda

Dentro do `global.asax` no metódo `Application_BeginRequest`, você adiciona duas linhas

```
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

Assim cada request vai ter sua própria cultura.

A primeira linha vai definir o  formato da data.

A segunda linha especifica qual recurso de localização carregar.

Comment: Testarei essa segunda opção. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Você está confundindo formato de armazenamento com formato de exibição de campos date ou timestamp.

Você não pode alterar o formato de armazenamento destes tipos de dados mas pode alterar o formato de exibição.

Consulte o item 8.5.2. (Date/Time Output) do manual:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

Com a utilização da função to_char você terá total controle de como exibir a data.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: Na verdade  eu precisava mudar o formato de armazenamento mesmo. Mesmo eu tratando ele no meu código depois com a cultura correta, ele estava salvando invertido no campo no banco. Resolvido como comentei aí na resposta. Pode não ser o mais correto mas por ora, resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @user3207729 Esse é ponto. Não existe "formato de armazenamento". O banco de dados salva dados tipo **DATA** e pronto - normalmente um inteiro que representa a quantidade de segundos desde `01/01/1900` ou algo do tipo. E isso vale para números flutuantes também, o BD salva **valores**, tanto faz se os decimais são separados por vírgula ou ponto. O que vai definir esse **formato** que te preocupa é a **exibição**, vc pode exibir datas no formato que bem entender: YYYYMMDD, DD/MM/YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY, etc.

Comment: @Thiago Lunardi: O que você descreveu acima não foi o "formato de armazenamento"?

Comment: @Anonimo Comecei falando: "Não existe "formato de armazenamento"".

Comment: @Thiago Lunardi: Se o que está armazenado no banco é um valor que representa uma data, no caso do tipo de dado date, ou um instante de tempo, no caso do tipo de dado timestamp, então este valor está armazenado de acordo com um formato inteligível pelo SGBD, portanto existe sim um formato de armazenamento, e o que está armazenado pode ser exibido nos mais variados formatos de exibição para data ou instante de tempo.

Answer (score 0):

Testei as soluções mas ainda não tivesse sucesso. Consegui resolver passando a data como parâmetro string no meu SQL usando o formato yyyy-MM-dd. Assim o postgre salva corretamente no campo timestamp.

Obrigado a todos pela dica. Serve de aprendizado. Valeu!

Comment: Repito que você está confundindo o formato de armazenamento de um campo date, ou timestamp, que é interno e você não pode alterar com o formato de exibição que você pode controlar a seu bel prazer.